# How to protect files from been access outside the network?

Tags: active-directory, filesystems, network-share, file-permissions

i am trying to find a solution regarding an issue that i am facing, we have a small server that is only used for sharing company files, their are some files that are created on employees company laptop that soon i am affraid they will be copied or taken to other competitors in the market.

So is their a solution where i can encrypt files and they are allowed only to be open within the network, files that are open outside the company network get corrupted or something and if they file is sent via email to a client he will be able to view it but not if sent to a personal account of the employee.

i hope i haven't confused anyone but i am lost, i searched about EFS and other features that are in related to encryption but couldn't find exactly what i need.

Really appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: If the information is leaving your company it can be stolen. If you have employees (and they have access to information) eventually the information will leave your company.  Your question is basically equivalent to "I want to display a web page, but not allow people to copy the text or print it" -- technologically it can't happen, and even if it could your security is defeated by a cell-phone camera or a pen and paper...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

What you want doesn't exist, and for various reason, essentially can't exist either.  The closest thing to what you're looking for is EFS, which will allow you to have the files only be decryptable by a domain account, which you could control, such as by changing the password to lock someone out of it.

Of course, once the files are decrypted, an employee can copy them any number of ways, and there's not a lot you can do about it.  You can look into data-leakage prevention software, but it's expensive, and doesn't work very well.  What's to stop someone from printing them out, taking a picture with a smartphone, writing the information down with a pen, memorizing the data, and so on?

At its core, this is not a technical problem, but a human and legal one.  The best way to handle this is to have strong NDAs, keep your people happy, and monitor the data that goes in and out of your network, with a web/mail filter, but there's just no way to lock down information as tightly as you want.  Even the US military and intelligence agencies can't keep data leaks from happening, and they spend massive piles of money trying, so you're certainly not going to be able to do it with a piece of software or free advice from the internet.

Answer (score 1):

There are tools out there for Information Rights Management, digital rights, ipsec, encryption, password protection, etc.  Some are software based, some are appliances, some are internal tools on enterprise networking equipment.

The problem with your question is that there are so many avenues to go down, hence the plethora of offerings.

Realize though that if there's a way somebody will circumvent it if they want.  Don't want your file printed?  Someone can screenshot it and print the screenshot.  Don't want your file taken offsite via USB?  Someone will email it to their personal email.

My best advice to you is to gather your needs/requirements as well as the types of files/apps you are wanting to secure and get with a VAR that has expertise in this area.  Trust me when I say you want a 3rd party to help you if for nothing more than to share the responsibility.